# Пропадает постер к видео после нажатия кнопки проигрывания

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Собственно, проблема описана в вопросе. Есть слайдер из видео, поверх видео лежит кнопка проигрывания, после ее нажатия запускается видео, а сама кнопка исчезает. Потом при перелистывании обратно кнопка появляется, и постер тоже - но его нет, отображается первый кадр видео только. Пробовала с помощью JS назначать, но тоже не выходит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<video
  preload="auto"
  poster="images/poster-2.png"
  muted
  src="video/slider-2.mp4"
  class="video video-2">
</video>
```

```
playBtn.forEach(p => {
p.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let video = e.currentTarget.closest('.slider__video-item').querySelector('video')
  video.play()
  e.target.style.display = 'none'
})
})

videos.forEach((v) => {
      v.style.transform = `translateX(${-49.78 * slide}rem)`;
      v.pause();
      v.currentTime = 0
      v.poster = 'images/poster-2.png'
});

playBtn.forEach(p => {
      p.style.display = 'block'
      p.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
})
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Так, а в чем вопрос ? Пропадет постер - да пропадает. Прочитайте что такое постер и его предназначение. Если вам необходимо какое-то изображение заглушку, вы можете поверх видео отображать дополнительное изображение при паузе.